# Where to learn about commas (academic/mathematical writing in particular)

Tags: grammar, commas, learning

I have recently tried to learn how to place commas properly when writing in
English, but I experienced a great difficulty in finding some good material on
the subject.

My goal is to be good (or at least okay) at placing commas in English text in
general, but it is mainly my academic writing I am concentrating on to begin
with.  More specifically, I am a mathematician, and it is in connection with
my mathematical writing that I most of all would like to learn to place
commas.

So far, the literature have had the following shortcomings:

- They only cover 'compound sentences' and 'complex sentences' but not
  'compound-complex sentences' of which there are tons in mathematics.
- Instead of teaching you about long-and-complicated sentences, they tell you
  to write/rewrite in short-and-simple sentences.  This is often not possible
  in mathematical writing.
- They are mainly books on grammar and punctuation, and often only have a
  small amount of information about placing commas.  I realize that you
  cannot write about placing commas without discussing grammar, but it would
  be nice if the commas where treated more thorough.
- Some focus a lot on direct speech which I do not use at all in my
  mathematical writing.
- Some literature seems to be a quite subjective opinion to comma placing,
  which does not necessarily agree with other places.
- Many places they give examples instead of rules.  This said, examples are
  good, and there should be a lot of them, but they should accompany
  rules/guidelines.
- They do not tell you when rules are definite rules (as much as they can be)
  and when they are not, that is, when there is a lot of exceptions.

What I am looking for are some good textbooks (or other means) from which I
can learn about placing commas.  Preferably avoiding the shortcomings I
mentioned above.  Especially the last point above would be nice to avoid.  I
looked at the *The blue book of grammar*, and in this book the author lists 21
rules about placing commas, but do not mention whether there are exceptions or
if some of them are just guidelines.  My impression is that some of them are
not definite rules (though I am clearly not an expert).

So far, I have tried books such as *Oxfords guide to English grammar*, *A
student's introduction to English grammar* and a few others.

Comment: *"Some literature seems to have a quite subjective opinion on common placing"* — comma placing ***is*** quite subjective, and you shouldn't listen to anybody who tells you otherwise.

Comment: @PeterShor:  Yes, you are of course right, and it was a pour way to formulate what I meant. What I meant was:  Sometimes it seems that people have _to subjective_ opinions. At least for the purpose of learning how to place commas. I would like to learn, roughly, what is the common practise or what are _possible correct ways_. If there, in a specific case, are several correct options (at leas considered so by the majority), then I would not prefer a guide that only mentions one of these and even tells me that this is the _only_ right way. PS This was probably more aimed at internet pages.

Answer (score 1):

Since English is so fluid, the 'common practice' of where commas go is very subjective, unfortunately.  I have not come across a book that I 100% agree with, however, there are a few fundamental places where commas SHOULD be used in the creation of meaning and their absence can cause a few unintentional mishaps. For example:

> *'Eat, Grandma!' Tom cried.*

Here, the comma indicates that Tom is addressing his gran and telling her to eat.  Without the comma, it would look like this:

> *'Eat Grandma!' Tom cried*

Here, the meaning changes dramatically.  Now, Tom is telling someone to eat his gran!

In these sorts of situations, subjectivity really should be reined in and a common practice adopted.

I recently wrote an article about the many uses of the comma that might be of some help to you, but like I said, I haven't found a book that I 100% agree with, so can't recommend one to you, sorry.  However, if you take a couple of texts and compare them, you can create your own style on the use of commas.  Below is mine.

http://carmelsealey.com/journal/the-importance-of-the-comma/

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  This was not really what I was lokking for, but your guide looks nice, and I will take a closer look at it.